# Which fb:// url is suitable to trigger the FB application prompting to share content?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova

Which of these urls in [This iPhone prefixes page](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook) starting with `fb://` is the one I must use to **share** content? (i.e. trigger the facebook application so the user can click to share the content passed with title, image, url, and summary).

I know the `http` alternative (starting with `http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100` - it works for me) but it triggers the browser and asks the user to log-in, even when the user is logged in the FB application. So in order to quicken everything, I want to make the FB app appear, showing a "share" screen with the preset content.

My intention comes from a Phonegap/Cordova application which shows product content and, for each product, a "share" link - There's no actual relationship between my app and Facebook (there's no fb app backend) - which should trigger the installed FB app prompting the user such content and waiting for his confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why going through all these trouble when there is a wonderful plugin. [Social Sharing Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)

This plugin will allow you to share in Facebook directly, also in other platforms if you want.

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook('Message via Facebook', null /* img */, null /* url */, function() {console.log('share ok')}, function(errormsg){alert(errormsg)});
```

Comment: It works! Althought if I share the URL, which I need, I cannot share the predefined text (i.e. it is overriden).

Comment: I read somewhere that it's the android quirks. I only used it to share image, so didn't face other issues @LuisMasuelli

Comment: Anyway, it saved my life :).